# Total count of spaces in specific dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to count the number of spaces present for all strings in `Col1`.

```
    Col1  Col2    file_name
0  AAA A   XYZ    test1.csv
1  B BBB   XYZ    test1.csv
2  CC CC   RST    test1.csv
3  DDDDD   XYZ    test2.csv
4  AAAAX   WXY    test3.csv
```

So I want the output to simply be something like:

`num_of_spaces = 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
num_of_spaces = df['Col1'].str.count(' ').sum()
```

Or, more efficient:

```
num_of_spaces = ''.join(df['Col1']).count(' ')

# or
# num_of_spaces = df['Col1'].str.cat(sep='').count(' ')
```

Output: `3`

##### timing:

original data:

```
%%timeit df['Col1'].str.count(' ').sum()
# 157 µs ± 6.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%%timeit ''.join(df['Col1']).count(' ')
# 4.74 µs ± 963 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%%timeit df['Col1'].apply(count_spaces).sum()
# 156 µs ± 9.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

50K rows

```
%%timeit df['Col1'].str.count(' ').sum()
# 24.7 ms ± 3.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit ''.join(df['Col1']).count(' ')
# 3.53 ms ± 377 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit df['Col1'].apply(count_spaces).sum()
# 19.1 ms ± 3.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Sir mozway I think to use numpy's char module, which provides a fast implementation of string operations.

Comment: using join is creative i am not gonna lie

Comment: @Mohamed thank you, and it's quite fast. I also tested `sum(x.count(' ') for x in df['Col1'])` which is faster than pandas but slower than the `join` version.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `apply()` method and the `lambda` function so:

```py
def count_spaces(x):
    return x.count(' ')

num_of_spaces = df['Col1'].apply(count_spaces).sum()
```

Output: `3`

Comment: why `lambda`, `.apply(count_spaces)` also works.

Comment: @QuangHoang Ah, I thought to provide a solution by making a custom function.

Comment: @Sunderam this is a valid solution, Quang's point was just that you don't need the `lambda x: …` Either use: `df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: x.count(' ')).sum()` or `df['Col1'].apply(count_spaces).sum()`, not both ;)

Comment: I timed it and, surprisingly, this is slightly faster than `str.count` on large datasets. I guess `str.count` is not really optimized

Comment: The numpy version is actually much slower (2x on small, 15x on 50K rows), likely due to the overhead of converting to numpy array ;)

Comment: @mozway what about using `applymap` to each element of df as `(df.applymap(lambda x: x.count(' '))).sum().sum()` ?

Comment: 2x slower than the original pandas

Comment: @mozway in my experience, generally `.str` is slower than `.apply` the same function, and is slower than list comprehension. They're there for convenience. That being said, the difference is usually small and I choose convenience over code complication :-).

Comment: @mozway I rolled back my answer to previous revision which you said as good.

Comment: @Quang yes it's true, this is not truly vectorized after all, just a wrapper for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This a different way of thinking also you can split on `space` and if there is 3 spaces this mean you will have 4 groups so `4-1` will give you the same result.
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1': ['AAA A', 'B BBB', 'CC CC', 'DDDDD', 'AAAAX'],
    'Col2': ['XYZ', 'XYZ', 'RST', 'XYZ', 'WXY'],
    'file_name': ['test1.csv', 'test1.csv', 'test2.csv', 'test2.csv', 'test3.csv']
})

df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(' ')) - 1).sum()
```

**Output
3**